# Bluetooth sound output on Android

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth

I just noticed, using the HTC Dream that using a bluetooth headset was really easy for phone calls, but nothing seemed to be available for videos / music sound output. V1.0 limitations are not at fault since when you play a music and start a call, you can hear the music in the headset for a second. So it's technically possible, just not available in the settings.

Does anybody knows how to redirect programatically the sound output to the blutooth headset ?

I'd like to code a little app that let you listen to your music while looking like a total idiot with a big device hanging to your hear :-)

N.B : this question is a copy of [the one I asked in Google group.](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c29b455707e5eba4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prior to Android 1.5, Bluetooth support was limited to the headset/handsfree profile. No "audio" other than the phone conversation could be redirected over Bluetooth.

Having installed Cupcake on my G1, I have now used Bluetooth stereo audio with my Motorola S9 headphones perfectly. The whole stack is even smart enough that they automatically pause the music/video, switch over to the headset profile when a call comes in and then back when the call finishes.

Comment: the headset isnt the one pausing the music, its androids media player!