# android - notification tone over bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, notifications

is there a way to play a tone over bluetooth?

I'm not trying to stream audio or anything fancy, I just want the headset to make a beep sound like when pressing an on screen button or getting a call.

Answer (score 0):

There is no current way to assign the device to play a sound. It will always play to the default output device.

If the Bluetooth headset is the default output device at that time, the MediaPlayer sounds will be heard in it.

[Audio and Video](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html)

> Audio and Video Playback
>
> Media can be played from anywhere:
>   from a raw resource, from a file from
>   the system, or from an available
>   network (URL).
>
> You can play back the audio data only
>   to the standard output device;
>   currently, that is the mobile device
>   speaker or Bluetooth headset. You
>   cannot play sound files in the
>   conversation audio.

Comment: Im making my bluetooth the output by:                                                    amanager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
         
         amanager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
         amanager.startBluetoothSco();
         amanager.setMode(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);          and trying both MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
    mp.start();                                                                  and tonegenerator to make sounds, but neither can be heard through the headset

Comment: Which version of Android your are using?  I just saw this post about not working on version 1. May not be related at all but just wanted to mention it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867897/bluetooth-sound-output-on-android

Comment: I am using 2.2, Ive also tried different modes besides STREAM_VOICE_CALLS, such as MODE_IN_CALL, but none of them gave me sound through the bluetooth either